# Access to API resource with Implicit flow

Tags: identityserver4

Does identity server 4 doesn't allow implicit flow to access API Resource.

Identity Server 4 config.cs

```
new Client
                {
                    ClientId = "implicit",
                    ClientName = "Implicit Client",
                    AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,

                    RedirectUris = { "https://notused" },
                    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "https://notused" },
                    FrontChannelLogoutUri = "http://localhost:5000/signout-idsrv", // for testing identityserver on localhost

                    AccessTokenLifetime = 10,
                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
                    AllowedScopes = { "openid", "profile", "email", "ProxyServer", "api" }
                }
```

Api Resouce

```
new ApiResource("api", "Custom"),
new ApiResource("ProxyServer", "Proxy Server")
```

In Mvc Client I am using this code ConfigureServices

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
            })
                .AddCookie(options =>
                {
                    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
                    options.Cookie.Name = "mvcimplicit";
                })
                .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = Constants.Authority;
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

                    options.ClientId = "implicit";

                    options.Scope.Clear();
                    options.Scope.Add("openid");
                    options.Scope.Add("ProxyServer");
                    options.Scope.Add("profile");
                    options.Scope.Add("email");

                    options.SaveTokens = true;

                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        NameClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Name,
                        RoleClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Role,
                    };
                });
```

When I try in browser I get "Sorry, there was an error : invalid_scope ". But if I remove **options.Scope.Add("ProxyServer");** it works fine and Identity server 4 take me to login page.

Answer (score 0):

OK I found the issue but posting just in case someone else face the same problem.

Response type needs to be specified explicitly otherwise it wont work.

```
options.ResponseType = "id_token token";
```

Modify the response type accordingly.